# Is there an Amazon EC2 AMI for TorqueBox 2.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, torquebox

I've been using TorqueBox for several months and was wondering if anyone knew of a public TorqueBax AMI for Amazon web services for the 2.x verson of TorqueBox.

I have searched the Internet several times, but to date have only come across what appears to be a TorqueBox 1.x version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deploy one of the free ubuntu images ( or any flavor linux you like)

Unpack torquebox2.2 to /opt

Unpack JDK1.7 under /opt/torquebox-2.2.0

Save the following to your bashrc

```
export TORQUEBOX_HOME=/opt/torquebox-2.2.0
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/torquebox-2.2.0/jdk1.7.0_10
export JBOSS_HOME=$TORQUEBOX_HOME/jboss
export JRUBY_HOME=$TORQUEBOX_HOME/jruby
export PATH=$JRUBY_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And you are done. 
Unless you mean an image that has examples of sites deployed using torquebox.

Comment: tven, do you actually have Torquebox running on EC2 or was your response more pro forma.  If you actually have it running are how is the performance, any pitfalls to be aware of. Many Thanks.

Comment: I have an ubuntu instance running torquebox right now. I will try to post some pitfalls here. We did hit a snag or two deploy jruby web application packaged as a war. Will get back to you.

Comment: Also, i cant comment about performance yet. I went with torquebox to test out the reported performance gains for Jruby/Rails deployment.

Comment: Thanks. look forward to your insights.

Comment: We had class loading errors for mysql jdbc driver. Fixed it with this articles help. http://itiansrock.blogspot.ru/2012/12/rails-32-with-jruby-and-mysql-with-rvm.html. I will post a deployment summary as soon as we can get that on paper. Just need the time to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I heard back via email from one of the project's developers and this is something on their list of things to implement.  Other user have had the same interest.